# Dialog box won't show when I run macro to save a document

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

This is the code I used. The dialog box only pops up when I run this in the designer. When I close the designer and run the macro it only saves the workbook, but I want the dialog box to pop up every time I run this macro. Any help/suggestions please

```
Sub SaveAs()
    Dim IntialName As String
    Dim sFileSaveName As Variant
    IntialName = "Sample Output"
    sFileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=InitialName, fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")

    If sFileSaveName <> False Then
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs sFileSaveName
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. There is a typo in the code you posted (`IntialName` instead of `InitialName` in the `Dim` and assignment statements). Once I correct that, the SaveFileAs dialog appears whether I run the method in the debugger or from a command button on a worksheet. Perhaps you should describe how you are calling `SaveAs` when you don't see the dialog.

Comment: @Blackwood: You found the error, so why don't you put up an answer.

Comment: @harrymc The error was just a typo in the question. It couldn't cause the behaviour described in the OP, in fact the code as written doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your Code needs few corrections:**

1. Since the Subroutine name used by you conflicts with one of the reserve words (command) **SaveAs**, therefore Excel Returns this error!

[image]

2. You need to remove this from command line, `InitialFileName:=`

**Reason:** You are trying to Save file with given Name, `IntialName = "Sample Output"`.

3. Last is typo, `InitialName`.

**Suggested corrections:**

- Rename the Subroutine for example, **SaveMyFileAs** or any other than **SaveAs**.
- Replace this line, `sFileSaveName =
  Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=InitialName, fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")`

*with this one,*

`sFileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(IntialName,
   fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")`

- You get Propmt.

[image]

- And this should the complete code to use.

  ```
  Sub SaveMyFileAs()

    Dim IntialName As String
    Dim sFileSaveName As Variant

    IntialName = "Sample Output"
  sFileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(IntialName, fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")

    If sFileSaveName <> False Then
      ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs sFileSaveName
    End If

     End Sub
  ```

**N.B.** This code can be use as, **Workbook_BeforeClose** event also.

Comment: Thank you ! It worked perfectly.

Comment: Gald to help you @BriDixon,, keep asking ☺